# C# Use Generics to Call Overridden Method

Tags: c#, generics, interface, overriding

I think I am a bit mixed up at this point, but I can't seem to be able to solve this issue.

I have an Interface `ILinkHandler<T>` and 4 other handler classes (inheriting from that interface) that validate different structures of links. From that interface, I have a `Task<List<T>> Validate()` function that does the validation of links and returns a Task> of results. Depending on `T`, I return a different model on `Validate()` (I have 4 different models).

My console app does the following. It calls the `Task<List<T>> Validate();` method of every link type and creates some logs after getting results (note that `Validate()` is `async`). Every log is a little bit different, since the model is different, so I overrode a method named `WriteResults(ModelX results, string name)` and from the ModelX type (see end of question, I posted 2 examples), I do some stuff different (not important on this scope I think, but I can provide details if necessary). This method is NOT async.

I wanted to use Generics and my Interface to create a method (`ValidateModel<T>`) that handles the right call to the overridden method `WriteResults` from the type of the model and calls the `Validate()` method from the interface.

The code below is that I did that worked, but the if part resembles what I currently have in my main and I want to avoid.

```
public void ValidateModel<T>(ILinkHandler<T> handler, string name) where T : class
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Validating {name}");
    var results = handler.Validate();

    if (typeof(T) == typeof(InternalLinksModel))
    {
        WriteResults(results.Result as List<InternalLinksModel>, name);
    }
    else // continue with other models
}
```

Here is what I have in my main:

```
private static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Validating External_Links");
    var resultsForExternalLinks = ExternalLinkHandler.Validate();
    WriteResults(resultsForExternalLinks.Result, "External_Links");

    Console.WriteLine("Validating Image_Links");
    var resultsForImageLinks = ImageLinkHandler.Validate();
    WriteResults(resultsForImageLinks.Result, "Image_Links");

// and so on
}
```

I want more something like this if possible, but this does not compile:

```
public void ValidateModel<T>(ILinkHandler<T> handler, string name) where T : class
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Validating {name}");
    var results = handler.Validate();

    WriteResults<T>(results.Result as List<T>, name);
}
```

Here is the definition of `WriteResults` (note that since it's overridden, I have 4 methods with their signature changing in the type of the list):

```
private void WriteResults(List<InternalLinksModel> results, string filename) { // Logs results into folder to display in jenkins }

private void WriteResults(List<PdfLinksModel> results, string filename) { // Logs results into folder to display in jenkins }

// and so on
```

## EDIT: Adding more code

Interface:

```
public interface ILinkHandler<T>
{   
    Task<List<T>> Validate();
}
```

Example of Handler Class inheriting the interface:

```
public class InternalLinkHandler : ILinkHandler<InternalLinksModel>
{
    public List<InternalLinksModel> InternalLinks = new List<InternalLinksModel>();

    public async Task<List<InternalLinksModel>> Validate()
    {
        // Here set up my tests, call tasks that modifies InternalLinks List and I await for its results
        return InternalLinks 
    }
```

Main Class (named `XmlLinkCheckerValidator`) where my code runs currently (and it works):

```
public class XmlLinkCheckerValidator
{
    // References to all modes
    public ExternalLinkHandler ExternalLinkHandler => new ExternalLinkHandler();
    public ImageLinkHandler ImageLinkHandler => new ImageLinkHandler();
    public InternalLinkHandler InternalLinkHandler => new InternalLinkHandler();
    public PdfLinkHandler PdfLinkHandler => new PdfLinkHandler();

    public void ValidateIPack()
    {
        InitialSetup();

        Console.WriteLine("Validating External_Links");
        var resultsForExternalLinks = ExternalLinkHandler.Validate();
        WriteResultsForIPacksInCsv(resultsForExternalLinks.Result, "External_Links");

        Console.WriteLine("Validating Image_Links");
        var resultsForImageLinks = ImageLinkHandler.Validate();
        WriteResultsForIPacksInCsv(resultsForImageLinks.Result, "Image_Links");

        Console.WriteLine("Validating Internal_Links");
        var resultsForInternalLinks = InternalLinkHandler.Validate();
        WriteResultsForIPacksInCsv(resultsForInternalLinks.Result, "Internal_Links");

        // Console.WriteLine("Validating Pdf Links");
        // var results = XmlLinkExtractorFromIPacks.PdfLinkHandler.Validate();
        // WriteResultsForIPacks(results, "Pdf Links");
    }

    private void WriteResultsForIPacksInCsv(List<InternalLinksModel> results, string filename) { logging results }

    private void WriteResultsForIPacksInCsv(List<ExternalLinksModel> results, string filename) { logging results }

    private void WriteResultsForIPacksInCsv(List<ImageLinksModel> results, string filename) { logging results }

    private void WriteResultsForIPacksInCsv(List<PdfLinksModel> results, string filename) { logging results }

    private void WriteResultsForIPacksInCsv(List<InternalLinksModel> results, string filename) { logging results }
```

Comment: You say that your `Validate` methods are async and return models, but in your example code they're just `void`?

Comment: What canton7 said is the cluprit I think. Make your methods async Task

Comment: ..."but this does not compile".  Well, whats the compiler error?

Comment: `ImageLinkHandler.Validate();` Where are the arguments?

Comment: It looks like there's a good question hidden in here, but since the text contradicts the code so much it's hard to work out what it is. Please edit your question until it's clear.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the definition of `WriteResults`?  Hard to tell how to call something that isn't shown.

Comment: I added my signature method of validate as written in the interface. There is no arguments in validate. The class handles the read of a csv file and proceeds to validate the info.

Comment: This is the compiler error I have: `cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnswerConnect.XmlLinkChecker.Data.Models.InternalLinksModel>'`

Comment: Your `Validate` method in your code does not return a `Task<List<T>>` -- it returns `void`.

Comment: Oh ok, I see where I mislead you. Both functions are named Validate, but they are not in the same scope. The one async is in the interface, while the other one is in the Main. I will change the name of the latter to avoid confusion

Comment: I will put code to make the question more clear. Really sorry about all the errors

Comment: @luisarcher  - Can you not have an interface `IHandleResult` that actually works with the individual results and update `ValidateModel` to also include `IHandleResult` in its definition.

Comment: @luisarcher You need to figure out what `InternalLinksModel`, etc. all have in common that WriteResults needs from them. Put that in an interface that `InternalLinksModel`, etc. all implement, then pass `IEnumerable<IWhateverInterface>` rather than a List of anything. You can cast those lists to that IEnumerable. You can't cast a `List<T>` to `List<BaseClassOfT>` because list lets you *add* items, and you can't add a base class instance to a list of subclasses of that class. You don't need or want List there. All WriteResults does is enumerate, so all it should ask for is an enumeration.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Ok, I think I understand. However, all my `XModel` class only contain properties, basically the number of columns within the csv file it's validating. They do have some common rows, however, they all have specific rows which only them have and I need to put in the logs. That's mainly the reason why I decide to override `WriteResults` method. I do understand the goal of your method and I will try to implement an `ILinkModel` to get rid of all the overridden methods. Thanks!

Comment: @luisarcher If they aren't all providing an identical thing, they can almost certainly provide disparate things in an identical way. The common interface could expose an enumeration of name/value pairs for logging, or something like that. Logging is a nice problem to run into because it all turns into strings anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally refactored all my code and it looks much clear. As I said, in the beginning, I think I got a bit mixed up and it all started from one bad design decision I took.

In short, I added a new method, `WriteResults(string filename)`. Doing so, I implemented the method and removed the overridden method (`WriteResultsForIPacksInCsv(List<WhateverModelIHad> results, string filename)`) from my "Main" class. From that, I changed the `Validate` method signature in the interface to `Task<List<PossibleResults>> Validate()` and since every model has that in common, I removed the generic in the interface. I can now call my handlers the following way:

```
public void Validate(ILinkHandler handler, string filename)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Validating {filename}");
    var results = handler.Validate();
    SetUpResultsStatistics(results.Result, $"{filename}_Statistics");
    handler.WriteResults(filename);
}
```

I created a function named `void SetUpResultsStatistics(List<PossibleResults> results, string filename)` which gives statistics of results and it is common to all handlers (thus, to avoid duplication I put it there).

Code is now much clearer and it now does not use any generics nor overridden method. I, however, am still curious as to how should I handle a case like that and will try to formulate it in another question with a much simpler example.

Thank you all for your comments, really appreciated!

Comment: For those interested in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58597045/c-sharp-generic-and-override-methods)