# C# Generic and override methods

Tags: c#, generics, interface, overriding

I created a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58594218/c-sharp-use-generics-to-call-overridden-method/58596492#58596492) and realized that it was due to some design error on my part. However, I do think that that concept can be useful and I would like to know how to solve an issue similar, if possible.

I want to create an algorithm that adds up 2 numbers, be it `string` or `int`. I also want to be able to output everything in the console and would like to avoid code duplication. I create a `generic interface` that changes according to the model. Then a class that handles the addition of the two members. Note that the data comes from the handler classes (which in real life scenario, get information to fill model from external data).

**Please note that I do know that I know there are much simpler ways of doping this, but I want to understand why it does not work.** Now, the code does not compile in the `ValidateHandler<T>(IAddHandler<T> handler)` due to `cannot convert from 'T' to 'Test.Models.StringModel'`. Why cannot it select the right overridden method ? I tried adding generics to the overridden method, but it still does not work. How can I make `ValidateHandler<T>`  select the right method from it's type ?

Here is the code I wrote.

Models:

```
public class IntegerModel
{
    public int A { get; set; }

    public int B { get; set; }

    public int C { get; set; }
}

public class StringModel
{
    public string A { get; set; }

    public string B { get; set; }

    public string C { get; set; }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface IAddHandler<T>
{
    T Add();

    void GetData();
}
```

Handlers:

```
public class IntegerHandler : IAddHandler<IntegerModel>
{
    public IntegerModel IntegerModel { get; set; }

    public void GetData()
    {
        // Get Info to Add from external file for example
        IntegerModel = new IntegerModel { A = 10, B = 20 };
    }

    public IntegerModel Add()
    {
        IntegerModel.C = IntegerModel.A + IntegerModel.B;

        return IntegerModel;
    }
 }

public class StringHandler : IAddHandler<StringModel>
{
    public StringModel StringModel { get; set; }

    public void GetData()
    {
        // Get Info to Add from external file for example
        StringModel = new StringModel { A = "10", B = "20" };
    }

    public StringModel Add()
    {
        StringModel.C = StringModel.A + StringModel.B;
        return StringModel;
    }
 }
```

Here is the Main with it's function

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var integerHandler = new IntegerHandler();
    var stringHandler = new StringHandler();

    ValidateHandler(integerHandler);
    ValidateHandler(stringHandler);
}

public static void ValidateHandler<T>(IAddHandler<T> handler)
{
    handler.GetData();
    var result = handler.Add();

    WriteResults(result);
}

public static void WriteResults(StringModel model)
{
    Console.WriteLine(model.C);
}

public static void WriteResults(IntegerModel model)
{
    Console.WriteLine(model.C);
}
```

I know I can do the following, but it seems ineffective in doing so and I do not see the point of using generics then.

```
public static void ValidateHandler<T>(IAddHandler<T> handler)
{
    handler.GetData();
    var result = handler.Add();

    if (typeof(T) == typeof(StringModel))
    {
        WriteResults(result as StringModel);
    }
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(IntegerModel))
    {
        WriteResults(result as IntegerModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Read up on [generic type constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) to get a better understanding of how to write generic code which *does* have some type information. But the most widely used genericss are things like `List<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>`, which need no type information at all.

Comment: So by creating a base class for model (Model<T>) that contains a definition of A B and C of type T, I could add `: where Model<T>` to `IAddHandler` and I would have access to property C then ? Since by forcing the generic to be derived of Model<T>, it would know about its properties ?

Comment: If you add `: where Model<T>` to IAddHandler, you'll find that you'll need a second type parameter: It'll have to be `IAddHandler<T, TModelParam> where T : Model<TModelParam>`. ValidateHandler becomes `void ValidateHandler<T, TModelParam>(IAddHandler<T, TModelParam> handler) where T : Model<TModelParam>`.

Comment: WriteResults becomes `WriteResults<TModelParam>(Model<TModelParam> result) { Console.WriteLine(result.Result); }`. So yes. My suggestion in your other question would be much simpler, and I would particularly recommend it if you haven't already figured out my last comment on your own, because that would mean you're just copying code you don't understand. But if you prefer this approach, it'll work.

Comment: The non-generic interface approach would also allow your model classes to "launder" results that can't trivially be stringified: For example, if the result is a list or enumeration, a non-generic Result overload could return `String.Join(", ", Result)`. But you could add a method to your generic Model base class to do the same.

Comment: You mean casting the `List<Model>` to `IEnumerable<Model>` ? I think I understood what you mean, however, decided not to implement it, since I found out that my design wasn't well thought. I'm still not used to `Generics`, I'm still very new to programming and in the work environment I am, they care more about results rather than proper clean code. Therefore, I can't spend much time refactoring my code, I did it this time because I finished a lot faster than expected and figured I could use the time left to improve what I had and learn a bit along the way.

Comment: The part about `IWhateverInterface`. Anything that provides a Result to be logged should implement a ***non-generic*** interface something like `interface IResult { object Result { get; } }`. The part about casting lists to enumerations applied to your attempt at passing an enumeration to WriteResults().

Comment: I do understand why you do not wan't to write the answer, being the fact that I will copy code that I do not understand. But I would appreciate if you do, since I think my question might help others

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201550/discussion-between-luisarcher-and-ed-plunkett).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd write a non-generic IModel interface which uses `object` instead of the type parameter, and implement it explicitly in your generic class.

Comment: I think this is a good answer, but -- "I believe it will be easier to get your head around than a fully generic solution. "  -- trying to decipher `public class IntegerHandler : IAddHandler<Model<int>>` from `public interface IAddHandler<T> where T : IModel` and `public class Model<T> : IModel` is not immediately obvious. (some comments might help)

Comment: @BurnsBA The solution OP was thinking of was somehow constraining T in IAddHandler to be `Model<T>` -- which would have to be `IAddHandler<T, TModelParam> where T : Model<TModelParam>`, thus `class StringHandler : IAddHandler<Model<String>, String>`, which IMO would be more troublesome for a beginner than a non-generic `IModel` interface. It was certainly more trouble for me. It wasn't a significant amount of trouble for me, but I've been doing this a while and OP hasn't.